# Best approach to check dataset has records

Tags: c#, dataset

I am keen to know the best approach to check if a dataset has records in it or not.
 I have been using the below code to check if a dataset has some records or not. But I feels there is some better/best approach available to achieve this.

```
Dataset tableData = New Dataset();
if (_tableData.Tables.Count > 0 && _tableData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{ 
}
```

Please share some knowledge if I am feeling correct.

Thanks

Comment: A DataSet is normally a container for multiple DataTables. I don't see the reason to know whether some of the DataSet's tables contains rows or not. Wouldn't it be less error-prone to check only the relevant DataTable for existing records instead? (even if your DataSet now contains only one table, this might change in future)

Comment: You are right Tim. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will return `true` if there are any rows in any of the tables. It will return `false` if there are no tables or no rows.

```
DataSet tableData; // ... instantiate DataSet
bool hasRows = tableData.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
                               .Any(table => table.Rows.Count != 0);
```

Comment: `Cast<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>` so no need to convert it again.

Comment: @Tomek Thanks - I've edited the answer accordingly. The `AsEnumerable()` was left in from an earlier edit (it did not have the `Cast<T>` before)

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple tables in your `DataSet` then your logic won't work for some scenarios.
This method is more complete:

```
bool HasRecords(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables) if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a query. As you are talking about multiple tables in the dataset, with this code, I'll be getting true always if there are two tables and first has rows and other has no rows.

Comment: Correct, you get true if there is any record in the `DataSet` no matter in which table. If you want to make sure all tables have a record: 
`bool HasRecords(DataSet dataSet)
{
 bool res = true;
 foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables) if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) res = false;
 return res;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check with [`HasChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.haschanges.aspx) which will be true only on successfull insertion of data including new, deleted, or modified rows

```
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        if (dSet.HasChanges())
        {

        }
```

You can also get it through [`DataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325617%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to know exactly what happened whether new row added, modified or deleted

Comment: will it be set to true if the rows are being modified? for example update/delete etc.

Answer (score 0):

Um well that isn't going to do the job if you have more than one DataTable in the DataSet.

Can't think of an occasion where I've needed to do this to be honest.  If I had a similar need, I'd be looking for the table in the DataSet on the assumption that all those in there were there for some functional reason.

So I might just check whether the customers table was empty with a select count, because if it is no point in checking anything else.

Comment: Correct. But here I know I have only one table. So just checking for one table. I'll definitely go for different approach if I am selecting multiple table. Nice point though.